# Chaining methods using Symbol#to_proc shorthand in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm wondering is there a way we can chain a method using (&:method)

For example:

```
array.reject { |x| x.strip.empty? }
```

To turn it into:

```
array.reject(&:strip.empty?)
```

I prefer the shorthand notation, due to its readability.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there's no shorthand for that. You could define a method:

```
def really_empty?(x)
  x.strip.empty?
end
```

and use [`method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-method):

```
array.reject(&method(:really_empty?))
```

or use a lambda:

```
really_empty = ->(x) { x.strip.empty? }
array.reject(&really_empty)
```

but I wouldn't call either of those better unless you have a use for `really_empty?` in enough places that splitting up the logic makes sense.

However, since you're using Rails, you could just use [`blank?`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank-3F) instead of `.strip.empty?`:

```
array.reject(&:blank?)
```

Note that `nil.blank?` is true whereas `nil.strip.empty?` just hands you an exception so they're not quite equivalent; however, you probably want to reject `nil`s as well so using `blank?` might be better anyway. `blank?` also returns true for `false`, `{}`, and `[]` but you probably don't have those in your array of strings.

Comment: You could also define the really_empty? method on the "array content class" (e.g. String) and then use it like the blank method. I am not advising this, just saying you could..

Answer (score 2):

It would be quite nice to write the above like that but it's not a supported syntax, the way that you would want to chain methods using the to_proc syntax (&:) is like so:

`.map(&:strip).reject(&:empty?)`

Comment: Though in all reality rather than trying to chain them together like that, I would opt to use your original example as it is.

Comment: I just ran a quick test out of interest and found that doing it your original way is over twice as fast (on my system) than doing it the double shorthand way (this makes sense as another temp array would have to be allocated as part of the `map`).

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to the party, but starting Ruby 2.6 you can do a [Proc composition](https://rubyreferences.github.io/rubychanges/2.6.html#proc-composition), which allows you to do, for example, this:

```rb
>> [:" aaa ", :"  ", :"ccc  "].map(&:to_s.to_proc >> :strip.to_proc >> :upcase.to_proc)
=> ["AAA", "", "CCC"]
```

This, of course, works with `reject`, too, so the original example in question would look like this:

```rb
[" aa ", "   ", "ccc   "].reject(&:strip.to_proc >> :empty?.to_proc)
# => [" aaa ", "ccc      "]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the `ampex` gem:

```
require 'ampex'
array.reject &X.strip.empty?
```