# Ruby: Can & operator work with several symbols at once?

Tags: ruby

For example, I have `enum.map(&:join).map(&:to_i)`. Is there a syntax in Ruby where I can write something like this: `enum.map(&:join:to_i)` in order to avoid iterating through the array twice using `&` operator?

Comment: Have you tested something ?

Comment: See @UriAgassi's answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23695653/can-you-supply-arguments-to-the-mapmethod-syntax-in-ruby/23711606#23711606). It's a masterpiece.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a block (with no `&`) to iterate just once:

```
enum.map { |e| e.join.to_i }
```

Comment: that's what I actually did. Is there anything could be done like that with & operator?

Comment: @Mikhail Oh, i see. I am not aware of any, i searched a while ago with no success. Is there a specific reason you need to use `&`? Or is a matter of style?

Comment: @Mikhail Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460204/chaining-methods-using-symbolto-proc-shorthand-in-ruby).